# Map Usb modem to serial port and network interface

Tags: usb, network-manager, usb-modem, serial-port

I have three Usb modem (W02-Lw43 JAZZ) plugged in.
Here some info :

```
_> ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:18:01:81:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.3/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:de:56:ff:01:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.100/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth1
       valid_lft 60961sec preferred_lft 60961sec
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:de:56:ff:01:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.11.100/24 brd 192.168.11.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth2
       valid_lft 60961sec preferred_lft 60961sec
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fc:de:56:ff:01:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.12.100/24 brd 192.168.12.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth3
       valid_lft 84051sec preferred_lft 84051sec

_> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 05c6:f00e Qualcomm, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05c6:f00e Qualcomm, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05c6:f00e Qualcomm, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2813 VIA Labs, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

_> ls /dev/
autofs           fd           kvm           memory_bandwidth    ptmx   ptypc     sr1     tty17  tty3   tty42  tty55    ttyAML2  ttyp9    vcs2   vcsu2
block            full         lirc0         mmcblk1             pts    ptypd     stderr  tty18  tty30  tty43  tty56    ttyS0    ttypa    vcs3   vcsu3
bsg              fuse         log           mmcblk1boot0        ptyp0  ptype     stdin   tty19  tty31  tty44  tty57    ttyS1    ttypb    vcs4   vcsu4
btrfs-control    gpiochip0    loop-control  mmcblk1boot1        ptyp1  ptypf     stdout  tty2   tty32  tty45  tty58    ttyS2    ttypc    vcs5   vcsu5
bus              gpiochip1    loop0         mmcblk1p1           ptyp2  ram0      tty     tty20  tty33  tty46  tty59    ttyS3    ttypd    vcs6   vcsu6
cdrom            hugepages    loop1         mmcblk1p2           ptyp3  ram1      tty0    tty21  tty34  tty47  tty6     ttyp0    ttype    vcsa   vfio
cec0             hwrng        loop2         mmcblk1rpmb         ptyp4  ram2      tty1    tty22  tty35  tty48  tty60    ttyp1    ttypf    vcsa1  vhci
cec1             i2c-0        loop3         mqueue              ptyp5  ram3      tty10   tty23  tty36  tty49  tty61    ttyp2    uhid     vcsa2  video0
char             i2c-1        loop4         net                 ptyp6  random    tty11   tty24  tty37  tty5   tty62    ttyp3    uinput   vcsa3  watchdog
console          i2c-2        loop5         network_latency     ptyp7  rfkill    tty12   tty25  tty38  tty50  tty63    ttyp4    uleds    vcsa4  watchdog0
cpu_dma_latency  iio:device0  loop6         network_throughput  ptyp8  shm       tty13   tty26  tty39  tty51  tty7     ttyp5    urandom  vcsa5  zero
cuse             initctl      loop7         null                ptyp9  snapshot  tty14   tty27  tty4   tty52  tty8     ttyp6    v4l      vcsa6  zram0
disk             input        mapper        ppp                 ptypa  snd       tty15   tty28  tty40  tty53  tty9     ttyp7    vcs      vcsu   zram1
dri              kmsg         mem           psaux               ptypb  sr0       tty16   tty29  tty41  tty54  ttyAML0  ttyp8    vcs1     vcsu1  zram2
```

My question is how can i map USB at (Bus:Device) to ethX and /dev/XXX.
For example :

```
USB                     Network interface       Port
Bus 001 Device 008      eth0                    /dev/ttyAML0
Bus 001 Device 006      eth1                    /dev/ttyAML2
Bus 001 Device 005      eth2                    /dev/???????
```

I don't have many knowledge of linux.
Thank you very much.

Comment: I can not answer your question properly. Some mapping is done by the system. Have a look here: https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Serial-HOWTO-10.html    Maybe you find the hint that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just answer it in case needed. I got the same question and found the answer on this [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/407080/identify-physical-network-device-by-interface-name-in-linux).

the mapping between the device name with the number can be found via the command :

```
$ ls -la /sys/class/net
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 Oct 29 12:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 56 root root 0 Oct 29 12:49 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Oct 29 12:49 eth0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/eth0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 Oct 29 12:49 lo -> ../../devices/virtual/net/lo
```